# Excel VBA Deleting Rows if Cells contain values

Tags: vba, excel

This is a part of a project I'm working on. It needs to look for the values in cells of the same row as the column I am checking. If it's No in A or empty in B, it needs to delete the row. It doesn't work but I don't understand why. Ay thoughts because I am really stuck?

```
`wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Activate
For Z = 1 To iNbKids
rGeo1 = "a" & Z
rGeo2 = "b" & Z
If wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Range(rGeo1).Value = "No" Then
ActiveSheet.Rows(Z).Select
Selection.Delete
ElseIf wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Range(rGeo2).Value = " " Then
ActiveSheet.Row(Z).Select
Selection.Delete
End If
Next Z`
```

Comment: Is that a space `" "` or a blank `""`..?

Answer (score 2):

The short of it is when adding or deleting rows one by one, iterate backwards:

```
For Z = iNbKids To 1 Step -1
    rGeo1 = "a" & Z
    rGeo2 = "b" & Z
    If wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Range(rGeo1).Value = "No" Or wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Range(rGeo2).Value = " " Then
        wb1.Worksheets("Loc").Rows(Z).Delete
    End If
Next Z
```

Also, instead of two if use an `Or`.

Another method to shorten the code is to use a With Block:

```
With wb1.Worksheets("Loc")
    For Z = iNbKids To 1 Step -1
        rGeo1 = "a" & Z
        rGeo2 = "b" & Z
        If .Range(rGeo1).Value = "No" Or .Range(rGeo2).Value = " " Then
            .Rows(Z).Delete
        End If
    Next Z
End With
```

No everything that has `.` in front will be like typing `wb1.Worksheets("Loc").` first.

Comment: Thank you kind soul. I tried something like that after searching but I didnt write the Step -1.. that was the problem

Comment: @RaphaelBoisvert glad to help.  Please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.